# how to get element that equal or greater than X but smaller than the next X in array?

Tags: javascript

So i want to get a number that greater than X in array but smaller than Y?
example I have array like this:
`["5","10","25",etc]`
then the value is 5, 
so what I want is whenever my value is 5 or greater than 5 but smaller than 10 in array it will only return the 5. like if the value is 6/7/8/9 it will return 5

(Note: The number in array will always different, it's depends on what user set in db)

I have tried with `givenNum >= nextNum` but it's returning with the number 10 and 25.

any solution?

Comment: please add your try and wanted result. btw, why strings?

Comment: So you want the element(s) that is greater than 5 but smaller than 10 in your example?

Comment: @Nina Scholz what strings?

Comment: @Mostafa Elkaramany no I mean if the given number is greater than 5 or equal it will give the 5 but smaller than the next number

Comment: you have strings as values.

Comment: oh yea it's string. because that's what I get from the user

Comment: What have you tried so far? share your code so we can help to solve the error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that :

```
var array = ["5","10","15","20","25"];
Math.max(...array.filter(nb => nb <= 9))//5
Math.max(...array.filter(nb => nb <= 10))//10
```

First, you filter the array to keep numbers that are less or equal to the given value.
Then you use `Math.max()` on the filtered array.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried with givenNum >= nextNum but it's returning with the number 10 and 25.

You are comparing strings instead of numbers, string comparison works alphabetically, since "1" comes before "5" alphabetically, "10" comes before "5" which is why "10" < "5" is true.

You need to convert your strings to numbers using [Number()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp) then compare.

Comment: I didn't comparing a string, the givenNum is 5 and the nextNum is 5 too, what I mean is if the user give 5 until 9 it will return 5, because it's less than 10 and greater/equal than 5